# <mvc:annotation-driven /> with un-annotated controllers

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

My project includes older un-annotated controllers together with newer annotation-based controllers.

I am using the latest Spring jars (3.0.5) and in my dispatcher-servlet.xml there's `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

The problem is that `<mvc:annotation-driven />` causes the request mapping (through the name property of the controller beans in the dispatcher-servlet.xml) to my un-annotated controllers not to work... each time I direct the request to an un-annotated controller I am getting an error message such as:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound  
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/some_path/some_page.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

How can I keep the un-annotated controllers as they are but tell spring to recognize their (old style) mapping?

I am looking for solutions with minimum change to the Java code of the controllers that I already have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your config, it replaces the default set of handler mappings and handler adapters, and those defaults were the ones that handled the old-style controllers.

You have 2 options. First thing to try is to remove `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. You can still use annotated controllers without this. It does add extra features like Jackson JSON support, but if you don't need those extra features, then you don't need it. So try your app without `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and see if it still works.

Failing that, you can reinstate the mappings and adapters for your old controllers. You didn't say how your controllers used to have their URLs mapped, but try adding these to your config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
```

If you used `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`, then that should be working already.

You also need to add the `HandlerAdapter` back in:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Don't just add these in blindly.  Try them individually, and see what the minimal set is to get your old controllers working alongside the new ones.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. My older controllers used the name=url method for mapping so I've added BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping to my dispatcher-servlet.xml and it works again now. Following your answer I've taken some time to read about handler mappings and handler adapters (didn't know about them). Now my question is in Spring 3, which handler mappings and handler adapters are automatically defined? I guess DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping & AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter but any others? Could you direct me to where it's mentioned in the documentation and/or code? Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

I found that by exploding the mvc:annotation-driven into it's actual replacement, it was easier to figure out.

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` explodes to this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configures a validator for spring to use -->
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageInterpolator">
        <bean class="com.eps.web.spring.validation.SpringMessageSourceMessageInterpolator" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="conversion-service" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

Once the magic was gone, I got this error trying to load an "Old" controller:
`javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@`

From that point, I added

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />
```

And all my old controllers worked.

Comment: Thank you, Brad, for your solution. It worked for me. Interesting that if I put "mvn:annotation-driven" into the configuration, then I get "Application has redirecting loop" error message, but exploded version is working OK.

Comment: I was using SimpleUrlHandlerMapping for the old controllers. With Spring 2.5.
Adding the following in enabled both annotated and old controller to work like a piece of cake!

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="[your package]"/>
 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

. Thanks!

Comment: Has anyone looking to why your solution worked? Was it because Spring came with a default adapter set, and defining the "AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" simple overwrote the default adapter setting?

Comment: hwo did you do the "exploding the mvc:annotation-driven into it's actual replacement" bit ?

Comment: I found a blog along time ago from one of the spring guys demystifying it, but I can't seem to find it again now.  Here is something similar, but the original one had the actual text above: http://thespringthing.blogspot.com/2010/10/what-does-mvcannotation-driven-do.html